Typescript not throwing error when passing wrong type props to child component
custom_types containing the wrong type of url as number instead of string
@types/index.ts
export type custom_types= {
  url: number;
}

Component.tsx
const Component: FC<{ tracks: custom_types[] }> = ({ tracks }) => {
   console.log(typeof tracks[0].url);      // string
   return (
        <div>
        </div>
   );
}

page.tsx
<Component tracks={userData.tracks} />

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}


I am getting in console of this line console.log(typeof tracks[0].url);
as string though it should be of type number with error I was just checking and the above code is sample code

Whats in your userData.tracks? Is it typed? if it's type is any typescript wouldn't be able to detect the issue

[
{
url: 'http://ransomurl',
}
]
array of the objects containing url of string type

Try refactoring to this const Component = ({ tracks }: custom_types[]) => {...}, and see if it works.

I have already tried this method also still not worked

I'm not asking what is in the data I'm asking what the interface is. Where does the initialization of the userData.tracks variable take place? Because I believe the issue is there, not in this component.

I am fetching userData from the api response and storing in userdata using usestate hook and passing it as props as userData.tracks
I made the child component props to be typed then it must throw error of url type should be number in same component but i am getting it correctly in string format without error

@Jasvindersingh What is the type of the variable you are assigning userData to after fetching? const [_a, _b] = useState<?>() what is the '?' in your case?

Ohh My bad, I got my mistake Thank You so much all for helping
